# Chrome browser console javascript about document.querySelectorAll('div') and document.querySelectorAll('div')[0]

Tags: javascript, console, frontend

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log(a)
alert(11)
```

The browser first outputs the contents of the console, then alert
however,change the demo

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div')[0];
console.log(a)
alert(11)
```

The browser first alert, and then output the contents of the console, the same applies to `document.getElementsByClassName`, check for a long time unsuccessful, but also hope to answer

Comment: Please say what browser you're using. (I do see this behavior in Chrome, though.)

Comment: I use Chrome ,thanks

Comment: There is no real answer to this question in the general case. Different browsers implement both the `console` and `alert` in different ways. `alert` has unusual stop-the-thread behavior and so it's not surprising that it interacts with the console in odd ways. In general, if you output/update something managed by the main UI thread and immediately call `alert`, don't expect that the update will be displayed until after the `alert` is dismissed. It may or may not be, depending on the browser and its internals.

Comment: Note that the line on which it will show the `div` **is** shown before the `alert` is dismissed in the second case; it's just the *content* of that line that waits. So apparently it has something to do with rendering the div (as opposed to a NodeList).

Comment: As far my understanding if the dev tool window is open then only this case will occur. On the case when it is off the code, will flow as it is written.

Comment: JavaScript is volatile across platforms. Therefore, you need to put checks in your code if you want to consistently execute code in a specific order.

Comment: @daddygames  Not sure what your getting at here, both version on any browser will execute in order.   All we are seeing here is how Chrome console handles a NodeList, compared to a Node.  A NodeList is known as a live collection, and this is most likely the reason.

Comment: @Keith maybe the comments are going that way, but there's no clear question being asked, so... All I'm saying is that if you want a guaranteed order of execution, you have to put checks in to ensure that order of execution. If the OP wants more of the "why" then okay, ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0):

In "You Don't Know JS: Async & Performance" Chapter 1:

> There is no specification or set of requirements around how the `console.*` methods work -- they are not officially part of JavaScript, but are instead added to JS by the hosting environment (see the Types & Grammar title of this book series).
>
> So, **different browsers and JS environments do as they please, which can sometimes lead to confusing behavior**.
>
> In particular, there are some browsers and some conditions that `console.log(..)` does **not actually immediately output** what it's given. The main reason this may happen is **because I/O is a very slow and blocking part of many programs (not just JS)**. So, it may perform better (from the page/UI perspective) for a browser to handle console I/O asynchronously in the background, without you perhaps even knowing that occurred.

As you can see from the output, `console.log(a)` is actually executed before `alert(11)`, except that the value of a is not displayed immediately.

[image]

After we click the OK button,

[image]

As you can see, the `div` tag is in the first line of the result. And the `undefined` in the next line is the result of `alert(11)`.